# Why `git add . ` command sometimes doesn't adds lockfile to staging area?

Tags: git, monorepo, pnpm

When I do `git add .` in a monorepo with pnpm, sometimes it doesn't include lockfile to staging area.

[image: Picture of source control after I do git add .]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to run the `git add .` from the root of the project such that git can parse through the file tree and stage the changes.

Make sure to not have lock file to the .gitignore file which `git add` commands respect when staging changes.

Use `git add -A` instead of `git add .` to add all the changes introduced after the recent commit in the repository instead of just staging changes in the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem for a year and I realized what was wrong while asking this question. Here is the problem for anyone else who encounters it.

So the project is a pnpm monorepo and I'm using vscode workspace so it opens my terminal inside of a project directory in monorepo.

```bash
-monoreporoot 
 |-apps
    |-project_1
 |-pnpm-lock.yaml
```

When I add a dependency on that project it changes the lockfile on the project root. But I'm doing `git add .` on `monoreporoot/apps/project_1` directory. So it turns out that `git add .` is adding all changes in the path you are on not the all changes in the git repository. It's quite obvious but they taught us this command adds all changes to the repository and I never think about it again.

Comment: In newer versions of git, you can use `git add -A` to add all files in the entire working tree. But this way you may add and commit unexpected files if gitignore is not properly customized.